# send image from server to client with REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, express, mongoose

I am trying to send an image that is stored in the server (currently in local storage) to the client. Here is part of my code

```
exports.get_icon = (req, res) => {

  App.findOne({name: req.body.name}, (error, application) => {
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    } else{
      console.log(application);

      res.status(200).send(application.iconImage) //!!need to do something here
    }
  })
}
```

this is the function which should fetch the path of where the image is stored and then send it to the client. Currently, the server sends the path of the image, not the image itself. Something like this `uploads/Twitter/icon.png`. So how could I send the image from the server to the client knowing that `application.iconImage` gives the path of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature in express to send the file via file path.

[res.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile)

```
app.get('/getImage/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(filepath);
});
```

However, I recommend you send the file path rather than the file as that is the best practice.

```
app.get('/getImage/:id', (req, res) => {
   res.send({ img: filePath });
})
```